# How to DATETIME regex and split

Tags: sql-server, datetime

```
USER  TIME
 A     2020-02-18 12:00:13.037
 B     2020-02-19 12:00:13.037
 B     2020-02-11 11:00:13.037
 B     2020-02-11 14:00:13.037
 B     2020-02-11 08:00:13.037
 C     2020-02-09 12:00:13.037
```

I want result like this:

```
USER  TIME
 B     02-11 
 B     02-11 
 B     02-11
```

Query time is 02-11 and split time to month and data

How can I do? My query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE USER = 'B' AND TIME REGEXP '02/11"
```

Comment: Can you show the query, please?

Comment: Use `DAY()`& `MONTH()` functions `[User] = 'B' AND DAY(Col) = 11 AND MONTH(Col) = 2`

Comment: Did you intend to include the result of your query? Which would be a syntax error because REGEXP is not a tsql function! And have you considered what happens when your source data spans multiple years? You still want all Feb 20 rows regardless of year? Focus on selecting the correct rows efficiently first - leave formatting to the consumer of the resultset. So far none of the responses are very efficient since they are not sargable.

Answer (score 1):

Get the `month` and the `date` from your `date` and use `DATEPART`:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [User] CHAR(1)
   ,[Time] DATETIME2
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([User], [Time])
VALUES ('A', '2020-02-18 12:00:13.037')
      ,('B', '2020-02-19 12:00:13.037')
      ,('B', '2020-02-11 11:00:13.037')
      ,('B', '2020-02-11 14:00:13.037')
      ,('B', '2020-02-11 08:00:13.037')
      ,('C', '2020-02-09 12:00:13.037');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
WHERE [User] = 'B'
    AND DATEPART(MONTH, [Time]) = 2
    AND DATEPART(DAY, [Time]) = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should work if I understand your question

```
CREATE TABLE #DATE ([USER] VARCHAR(5),  [TIME] DATETIME2)
INSERT INTO #DATE VALUES
('A','2020-02-18 12:00:13.037'),('B','2020-02-19 12:00:13.037'),
('B','2020-02-11 11:00:13.037'),('B','2020-02-11 14:00:13.037'),
('B','2020-02-11 08:00:13.037'),('C','2020-02-09 12:00:13.037')

SELECT
    [USER],  
    [TIME],
    FORMAT([TIME],'MM-dd')
FROM #DATE
WHERE FORMAT([TIME],'MM-dd')='02-11'

DROP TABLE #DATE
```

NOTE that the format function only work for SQL Server version 2012 and above.

Comment: [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). BTW, 2012 is the oldest supported version since last July.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you the results in the format mentioned in the question if you want to return records based on the query running date

```
SELECT [USer], FORMAT ([Time], 'MM-dd') as [time]
from [Table1]
where FORMAT ([Time], 'MM-dd')=FORMAT (getdate(), 'MM-dd') and [user]="B"
```

If you want results based on hard-coded date the following query will work

```
SELECT [USer], FORMAT ([Time], 'MM-dd') as [time]
from [Table1]
where FORMAT ([Time], 'MM-dd')='02-11' and [user]="B"
```